# Use KNN as a clustering method

Tags: k-nn

I am trying to use KNN as an Unsupervised clustering. Yes, I know KNN is supposed to be a used as a classifier, using I was given a task to use it as a clustering model).

I am using this link from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) documentation as a reference:

```
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
>>> nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(X)
>>> distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(X)
>>> indices
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 3],
       [5, 4]]...)
>>> distances
array([[0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.        , 1.41421356],
       [0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.        , 1.41421356]])

>>> dist_matrix = nbrs.kneighbors_graph(X).toarray()
array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```

To help you visualize the problem, this is the data (X):

[image]

And this is the desired result:

```
desired_result = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

My question is what is a computationally efficient way to construct the underlying clusters from the `dist_matrix` (or from the `indices` array)

Comment: How do you construct the clusters from `dist_matrix`?  Depending on the approach one may think about improving efficiency

Comment: I changed the question. I am not looking for the most efficient solution right now, just for a solution that is "good enough". I have a feeling that this problem already have an implemented solution somewhere